# How to change object values in a function outside that object, vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to change the values of an object using function outside of that object, so that I can access those values later (in yet another objects).

I am new to programming, apologies if there is something wrong in my description or question.

For instance,

```js
let myObject = {
  startTime: '',
  endTime: '',
  newId: '',
    
  set setStartTime (val) {
    this.startTime = val
  }
}
    
stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const {startTime, endTime, newId} = myObject

  myObject.setStartTime = new Date()
    
})

console.log(myObject.startTime)
```

So when I console log `myObject.startTime` - in the console its value is empty.  Apparently, because it just logs the initial (unchanged value).  Why does this happen, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> when I console log 'myObject.startTime' - in the console its value is
> empty

Because your code when it loads at first time will show the initial value of *`myObject`* which is empty. After you click on *`stopButton`* will change but not log any thing, because `console.log(myObject.startTime)` outside of function, *Solution*, put `console.log` inside of click of `stopButton`.

```js
var dateNow = null;//declare it globally here
stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const {startTime, endTime, newId} = myObject

  myObject.setStartTime = new Date()
  dateNow = myObject.setStartTime;//<-- assign it value here
})

console.log(dateNow )//<-- call it outside of function here
```

> if I can use that new value (generated inside a function) outside of
> that function?

Yes you can, just declare a variable globally (outside of function ) to hold the generated value inside click function; then you can call it outside of it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The question is if I can use that new value (generated inside a function) outside of that function?  That's the issue I am trying to solve

Comment: I've updated the answer check it out! hope you helped!